# Visual Studio 2019 Compatibility for SSIS Development with SQL Server 2022

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, sql-server-2022

My organization will be upgrading our SQL Servers to SQL 2022 soon. I have heard through our IT grapevine that the provider for SQL Server 2022 has changed in SSIS and therefore that SSIS development post-SQL'22-migration now requires Visual Studio 2022 (most of our dev teams currently use VS 2019).

I can't seem to find any Microsoft documentation that speaks to this directly. Can anyone confirm this requirement and point me to the Microsoft documentation that validates it? Thanks.

Comment: I cannot point you to any documentation, because I know it to not be true. I use Visual Studio 2019 daily, and I deploy to 2022 instances; that includes today.

Comment: I admit, it's on the cards to update to VS 2022 but getting the entire team updated, and things tested, hasn't been a worthwhile time investment.

Comment: @Thom A, Confirming.. the deployments to the 2022 instances that you're referring to are SSIS deployments, correct?

Comment: Correct, yes...